# How to wire a JSON data from file in Spring?

Tags: java, json, spring

I have a simple Spring App. In that app I have `@Repository` which should provide access to `JSON` file with my data.

```
@Repository("jsonStorageUserRepository")
public class JsonUserRepository implements UserRepository {

    @Value("${users}")
    private List<User> users;

    @Override
    public User getByCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        return users.get(cursor.getId);
    }
}
```

My `users.json` file (storage) in `properties` folder -

```
[
    {
        "name": "Bill",
        "registered": true
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "registered": true
    }
]
```

And my `DTO` class -

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private boolean registered;
    private String name;

    public User(String name, boolean redistricted) {
        this.name = name;
        registered = redistricted;
    }
    // setters and getters were omitted
}
```

Right now I have exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jsonStorageUserRepository': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.List com.springapp.mvc.repository.json.JsonUserRepository.users; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'users' in string value "${users}"
```

It related to this line -

```
@Value("${users}")
private List<User> users;
```

Is it possible to wire converted List of entities from `JSON`?

Comment: Where do you expect `${users}` to come from and why?

Comment: In my `properties` project folder I have a file `users.json`. I want to read property from there. I store in this file my data.

Comment: Why do you think what you've shown us accomplishes that?

Comment: No, my code doesn't work. The problem is how to read properties in json format and wite them into some component bean.

Comment: The question was `How to force Spring to read properties form *.json file?`

Answer (score 0):

It will not work reading JSON-format-properties file. You need write your custom property editor. Have a look at that article:

http://christopherhunt-software.blogspot.de/2010/04/spring-propertyeditor-for-json-map-and.html

Answer (score 0):

spring doesn't find your property file:

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'users' in string value "${users}"
```

at

```
@Value("${users}")
```

Maybe the PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer is wrong configured.

Comment: @Alex Please Show your context.XML. So we can see where the Problem is.

Comment: In my context I don't have any `CustomEditorConfigurer`. I'm trying to implement it...